# Implementation of Matlab API ordfilt2 in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am translating the code written in Matlab to OpenCV.
In Matlab, there is ordfilt2 function.
Is there any similar implementation in OpenCV?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the ordfilt2() in Matlab using erosion or dilation in OpenCV. `ordfilt2(A,1,ones(3,3))` in Matlab is erosion function and can be replaced with `cv::erode(im, mx, mk,cv::Point(-1,-1),1,BORDER_CONSTANT );` in OpenCV. ordfilt2(A,9,ones(3,3)) in Matlab is dilation and can be replaced with `cv::dilate(im, mx, mk,cv::Point(-1,-1),1,BORDER_CONSTANT );`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general one. Browse [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html) to find if something suits you.

From Matlab help:

> B = ordfilt2(A, order, domain) replaces each element in A by the
>   orderth element in the sorted set of neighbors specified by the
>   nonzero elements in domain.

So you have an image A, and your slide a kernel(domain) which sorts pixel values and you pick always one specific order.

OpenCV steps (for a grayscale image):

1) clone image canvas

2) slide on each pixel of the canvas

3) create a vector of a subregion of the same pixel on your image

4) sort the vector

5) set the new image pixel value to the desired vector element.

Answer (score 0):

```
dilation = ordfilt2(proj, 5, ones(1,5));  %in matlab

Following is my implementation in opencv, proj is 1D matrix of size (26,1)
Mat dilation = proj.clone(); Mat array = Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_32FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        (i - 2) < 0 ? array.at<float>(0, 0) = 0 : array.at<float>(0, 0) = proj.at<float>(i - 2, 0);
        (i - 1) < 0 ? array.at<float>(1, 0) = 0 : array.at<float>(1, 0) = proj.at<float>(i - 1, 0);
        (i) < 0 ? array.at<float>(2, 0) = 0 : array.at<float>(2, 0) = proj.at<float>(i, 0);
        (i + 1) >= 26? array.at<float>(3, 0) = 0 : array.at<float>(3, 0) = proj.at<float>(i + 1, 0);
        (i + 2) >= 26? array.at<float>(4, 0) = 0 : array.at<float>(4, 0) = proj.at<float>(i + 2, 0);
        float temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (temp < array.at<float>(j, 0))
                temp = array.at<float>(j, 0);
        }
        dilation.at<float>(i, 0) = temp;
    }
```